google spreadsheet for portfolio tracking
I have code for amzn price
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price")
ans is= 185.67

Now i added my quantity to price
=multiply(GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price"),25)
ans is= 4641.75

Then i have generated a sprakline for 365 days
=SPARKLINE(GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","Price",TODAY()-365,TODAY()))

and now i want to merg this two code into single code but it is not working
=SPARKLINE(index(multiply(GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price"),25),GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price",WORKDAY(TODAY()-365,TODAY()))))

